# Using a USB to I2C adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu 18.04, and would like to get a USB to I2C adapter [here](https://www.robotshop.com/en/devantect-usb-to-i2c-spi-serial-interface.html) to work on it using command line so I can do some basic tests on several sensors. What I've learned so far: my adapter likely creates a virtual serial port that I can use to communicate with I2C devices. Running `dmesg` shows that the adapter can be found on /dev/ttyACM0. I can write to /dev/ttyACM0 with, say, `printf '<bytes here>' > /dev/ttyACM0`. So far I had no luck getting a device to respond in any way, so I was wondering the following: is there any standard test I can do to figure out if my connection is actually working? Also, how can I read output (if any) from my devices using /dev/ttyACM0 on the command line?
Update: I managed to get a response by running `cat /dev/ttyACM0` and from a second terminal sending `echo 'd' > /dev/ttyACM0`. That shows up as a vertical space in the cat terminal. If I use 'b' instead of a 'd', it prints a question mark within a rhombus. However, no other values, including commands listed as supported by the adapter, seem to give any response.